# SQLite query results with pipes | |

Tags: sqlite

I have a database for music. One of the tables is named tracks and when I execute the query

```
SELECT * FROM tracks

idTrack strPath strArtist   strAlbumArtist  strAlbum    strGenre    strComposer strConductor    strTitle    iTrack  iNumTracks  iDuration   iYear   iTimesPlayed    iRating iFavorite   iResumeAt   iDisc   iNumDisc    strLyrics   strComment  strFileType strFullCodec    strBitRateMode  iBPM    iBitRate    iChannels   iSampleRate dateLastPlayed  dateAdded
1   \\MEDIA-SERVER\Music\112\112\01 112 - 112 - Intro.flac  | 112 | | 112 |     112 | R&B | |  |        112 Intro   1   0   133 1996    0   0   0   0   0   0           flac    Flac Audio      0   896 2   44100   0001-01-01 00:00:00 2013-11-02 12:46:35
2   \\MEDIA-SERVER\Music\112\112\02 112 - Now That We're Done.flac  | 112 | | 112 |     112 | R&B | |  |        Now That We're Done 2   0   309 1996    0   0   0   0   0   0           flac    Flac Audio      0   912 2   44100   0001-01-01 00:00:00 2013-11-02 12:46:35
3   \\MEDIA-SERVER\Music\112\112\03 112 - Pleasure & Pain.flac  | 112 | | 112 |     112 | R&B | |  |        Pleasure & Pain 3   0   257 1996    0   0   0   0   0   0           flac    Flac Audio      0   923 2   44100   0001-01-01 00:00:00 2013-11-02 12:46:35
```

the results are filled in with | 112 | but if I execute the query

```
SELECT strArtist FROM tracks

strArtist
|  |
|  |
|  |
```

then I end up with strArtist containing nothing but | |

Why are the results blank if I specify a column? Do the pipes | | around the results have anything to do with it? They are around the results in the column `strArtist` when I do a `SELECT * FROM tracks`. Same thing for the columns `strAlbumArtist` and `strGenre`.

The values are not it the wrong spots. I exported the results using tab delimited to text file so they look like off but they aren't.

I get they same results from SQLabs Group SQLiteManager, Firefox tool SQLite Manager, and in C#.

Comment: How are you executing the query?

Comment: Can you show the output of both queries?

Comment: The values aren't NULL because when I execute SELECT * FROM tracks, they are filled with values. These values are surrounded by ||. If I execute SELECT strArtist FROM tracks WHERE strArtist is not NULL, I get the same number of results but they just contain ||

Comment: What tool are you using to run the query? Is this the stand-alone sqlite program, or via one of the embeddings in some programming language?

Comment: If those values are correct, it looks like an import may have gone wrong - the separators in the first list make it appear that both the ID number and path went into `idTrack`, with the first `112` going to `strPath`, and the empty field following that (before the next `112`) is actually `strArtist`.  What does `select idTrack from tracks` show? What about `select strPath from tracks`?